# Find value in Matrix with google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, lookup-tables

I have a google sheet with a row of months and a column of names. So each Name has a number in each month. Kind of like a matrix or two dimensional array.
What I want is
(1) Finde the Month with the highest number for a certain name (relative cells)
(2) Find the highest number for a certain name (relative cells again)

The solution may be to combine vlookup with hlookup or is there a certain formula for this kind of problem?

EXAMPLE: If I type in "Name 3" I would like (1) Januar and (2) "7".

[image: Examplesheet]

Answer (score 2):

For example, look for name 2:

`=FILTER($1:$1,OFFSET(A1,MATCH("name2",A2:A,0),0,1,columns(1:1))=max(OFFSET(A1,MATCH("name2",A2:A,0),0,1,columns(1:1))))`

change "name2" in this formula to cell refference and enter ther name you look for. This formula will give the number of month with the biggest number for name2, or other selected name.

---

And the maximum value is:
`=max(OFFSET(A1,MATCH("name2",A2:A,0),0,1,columns(1:1)))`

Same logic, just part of formula #1

Comment: What does the "columns(1:1)" part mean? I cant find this in the docu...

Comment: Same for $1:$1... Does that address the whole sheet?

Comment: The table is in a different sheet called "'Zahlen'!A15:M15". I just could not get it to work: =FILTER(Zahlen!A15:M15; OFFSET(Zahlen!A15; MATCH(B1; Zahlen!A15:A; 0); 0; 1;columns(Zahlen!A15:M15))=max(OFFSET(Zahlen!A15;MATCH(B2; Zahlen!A16:A; 0); 0; 1;columns(Zahlen!A15:M15))))

Comment: Ok, I know the problem now: This is upside down. I already now the month, but I am trying to find the name for the maximum value in a certain row (that I already know). How would I do this?